# Angular 9 - Add removed li to another ul - Eventbinding

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, event-binding, property-binding

Hello everyone =) I have started to practice Angualar 9 and I really like the component approach. In order to practice property and eventbinding, i started a project of deckbuilding component with two lists. English is not my main language but I will try to explain clearly.

**IMPORTANT** : I really want to practice this tool, so could you, in the answer, explain your reasoning ? If you have solution tracks, i can search by myself too in order to learn.

**GOAL** :

I have two lists (CardlistComponent and DecklistComponent) and each time i click on one LI in CardListComponent (or DecklistComponent), this same element is removed but added to the other list.

**COMPONENTS** :

1. DeckbuilderComponent which contains my two other components (the two lists)
2. CardlistComponent (the first list)
3. DecklistComponent (the second list)

**ISSUE** :

I can remove the element in CardlistComponent, but I can't add the same element to the DecklistComponent. I guess the problem is the way I use arrays in Javascript.

***DeckbuilderComponent (HTML)*** (Parent component)

```
<app-cardlist></app-cardlist>
<app-decklist
  (cardAdded)="onCardAdded($event)">
</app-decklist>
```

***DeckbuilderComponent (TS) *** (Parent component) I guess one of the problems is here because I duplicated the logic of add an item in the parent **AND** in DecklistComponent

```
  @Output() cardAdded = new EventEmitter<{name: string}>();

  decklist: Card[] = [
    new Card('CardC'),
    new Card('CardD')
  ]

  onCardAdded(element : HTMLLIElement){
    this.decklist.push({
    name: element.textContent
  })
 }
```

***CardlistComponent***

```
  @Output() cardRemoved = new EventEmitter<{cardName: string}>();

  cardlist: Card[] = [
    new Card('CardA'),
    new Card('CardB')
  ]

 removeCard(indexCard: number, element: HTMLLIElement){
   this.cardlist.splice(indexCard, 1)
   this.cardRemoved.emit({
   cardName: element.textContent
 });
```

***DecklistComponent*** this list has to recieve the element removed in the first list

```
  @Input() cardName: {name: string};

  decklist: Card[] = [
    new Card('CardC'),
    new Card('CardD')
  ]

  onCardAdded(element : HTMLLIElement){ 
    this.decklist.push({
    name: element.textContent
  })
}
```

---

Here is the HTML of my two components just in case.

***DecklistComponent (HTML)***

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li
        *ngFor="let card of decklist; let indexCard=index"
        class="list-group-item"
        #cardName
        >
            <a href="#"  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" >{{ card.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***CardlistComponent (HTML)***

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li *ngFor="let card of cardlist; let indexCard=index" class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#"
            (click)="removeCard(indexCard, card)"
            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ card.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want something else I didn't mention, don't hesitate to tell me and have a nice day full of code =D

Comment: You are interacting in two components via `@Input` and `@Output` then they must have same parent. If you have this parent -child structure we would like to see your parent components html and ts

Comment: @Kenny You are right, I added the parent (Deckbuilder). I understand better where the problem is, but not how to fix it.

Comment: As u state the issue could be the arrays. Instead of deleting by name you could consider using index. When you do ur *ngFor you can add index inside and then parse that to the child component - then use that index for manipulation of cards instead

Answer (score 0):

You can design `DeckbuilderComponent` as Container Component and `CardlistComponent, DecklistComponent` as Presentational Components

[source](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-component-design-how-to-avoid-custom-event-bubbling-and-extraneous-properties-in-the-local-component-tree)

> Container Components: These components know how to retrieve data from
>   the service layer. Note that the top-level component of a route is
>   usually a Container Component, and that is why this type of components
>   where originally named like that
>
> Presentational Components - these components simply take data as input
>   and know how to display it on the screen. They also can emit custom
>   events

```html
<deck-list (remove)="removeAndMoveTo($event, deckList, cardList)" [items]="deckList"></deck-list>
<card-list (remove)="removeAndMoveTo($event, cardList, deckList)" [items]="cardList"></card-list>
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li *ngFor="let card of cardlist; let indexCard=index" class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#"
            (click)="removeCard(card)"
            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ card.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
class CardlistComponent {

  @Output("remove") removeCardEmitter: EventEmitter<Card>;

  constructor() {
    this.removeCardEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  }

  removeCard(card: Card){
    this.removeCardEmitter.emit(card);
  };

}
```

```js
class DeckbuilderComponent {

  cardList: Card[];
  decklist: Card[];

  constructor() {
    this.cardList = [
      new Card('CardA'),
      new Card('CardB')
    ];

    this.decklist = [
      new Card('CardC'),
      new Card('CardD')
    ];
  }

  removeAndMoveTo(card: Card, sourceList: Card[], targetList: Card[]) {
    this.sourceList = this.sourceList.filter(pr => pr.id === card.id);
    this.targetList.push(card);
  }
}
```

Of course they are many solution to move element from one list to another. You can as well have one list and each card has some information to which group it belongs. Then `value` input binder would look like `[items]="list.filter(pr => pr.isInCardList)`.

Another single-list approach might use rxjs. One observable which gets split with [partition](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/partition) operator

Comment: I will adapt my code later, but thank you for your answer, i will check your source to understand properly